# Redirect root to /admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, activeadmin

I have a really strange issue, in one moment I get this working but now is always failing.

I want the /admin suffix to be the root page of my app.

I tried:

```
root to: redirect('/admin')
  devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
```

This:

```
  devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
  get '/', to: redirect('/admin')
```

And this (without luck):

```
  devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
  root to: 'admin/dashboard#index'
```

I think the last option was the snippet working yesterday but I'm not sure.

EDIT ** RAKE ROUTES ADDED **

```
Prefix Verb       URI Pattern                               Controller#Action
                          root GET        /                                         admin/dashboard#index
                    admin_root GET        /admin(.:format)                          admin/dashboard#index
batch_action_admin_admin_users POST       /admin/admin_users/batch_action(.:format) admin/admin_users#batch_action
             admin_admin_users GET        /admin/admin_users(.:format)              admin/admin_users#index
                               POST       /admin/admin_users(.:format)              admin/admin_users#create
          new_admin_admin_user GET        /admin/admin_users/new(.:format)          admin/admin_users#new
         edit_admin_admin_user GET        /admin/admin_users/:id/edit(.:format)     admin/admin_users#edit
              admin_admin_user GET        /admin/admin_users/:id(.:format)          admin/admin_users#show
                               PATCH      /admin/admin_users/:id(.:format)          admin/admin_users#update
                               PUT        /admin/admin_users/:id(.:format)          admin/admin_users#update
                               DELETE     /admin/admin_users/:id(.:format)          admin/admin_users#destroy
      batch_action_admin_cases POST       /admin/cases/batch_action(.:format)       admin/cases#batch_action
                   admin_cases GET        /admin/cases(.:format)                    admin/cases#index
                               POST       /admin/cases(.:format)                    admin/cases#create
                new_admin_case GET        /admin/cases/new(.:format)                admin/cases#new
               edit_admin_case GET        /admin/cases/:id/edit(.:format)           admin/cases#edit
                    admin_case GET        /admin/cases/:id(.:format)                admin/cases#show
                               PATCH      /admin/cases/:id(.:format)                admin/cases#update
                               PUT        /admin/cases/:id(.:format)                admin/cases#update
                               DELETE     /admin/cases/:id(.:format)                admin/cases#destroy
               admin_dashboard GET        /admin/dashboard(.:format)                admin/dashboard#index
       batch_action_admin_tags POST       /admin/tags/batch_action(.:format)        admin/tags#batch_action
                    admin_tags GET        /admin/tags(.:format)                     admin/tags#index
                               POST       /admin/tags(.:format)                     admin/tags#create
                 new_admin_tag GET        /admin/tags/new(.:format)                 admin/tags#new
                edit_admin_tag GET        /admin/tags/:id/edit(.:format)            admin/tags#edit
                     admin_tag GET        /admin/tags/:id(.:format)                 admin/tags#show
                               PATCH      /admin/tags/:id(.:format)                 admin/tags#update
                               PUT        /admin/tags/:id(.:format)                 admin/tags#update
                               DELETE     /admin/tags/:id(.:format)                 admin/tags#destroy
                admin_comments GET        /admin/comments(.:format)                 admin/comments#index
                               POST       /admin/comments(.:format)                 admin/comments#create
                 admin_comment GET        /admin/comments/:id(.:format)             admin/comments#show
        new_admin_user_session GET        /admin/login(.:format)                    active_admin/devise/sessions#new
            admin_user_session POST       /admin/login(.:format)                    active_admin/devise/sessions#create
    destroy_admin_user_session DELETE|GET /admin/logout(.:format)                   active_admin/devise/sessions#destroy
           admin_user_password POST       /admin/password(.:format)                 active_admin/devise/passwords#create
       new_admin_user_password GET        /admin/password/new(.:format)             active_admin/devise/passwords#new
      edit_admin_user_password GET        /admin/password/edit(.:format)            active_admin/devise/passwords#edit
                               PATCH      /admin/password(.:format)                 active_admin/devise/passwords#update
                               PUT        /admin/password(.:format)                 active_admin/devise/passwords#update
```

What you suggest to do that? Any idea?

Comment: Is there a model for admin?

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm using active_admin. So there's a model called admin_user

Answer (score 8):

You've almost got it right!

You set your root path to: `root to: redirect('/admin')`

With that, you also have to explicitly declare the route to which it's being routed, like so: `match '/admin', to: 'admin/dashboard#index', via: :get`

That way, your root path will automatically call the latter route and controller every time it's called.

Just to clarify, your setup will look like this:

```
TestActiveAdmin::Application.routes.draw do 
  root to: redirect('/admin')
  match '/admin', to: 'admin/dashboard#index', via: :get

  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)

  devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config

  ...
end
```

Then you can verify in your Rails console: `rake routes | grep root`

You should see something like: 
`root /admin {:controller => 'admin/dashboard, :action => 'index'`

Comment: This doesn't work, it's weird. I will edit the post with the routes obtained with rake routes...

Comment: In addition "match" fails at start saying: "You should not use the `match` method in your router without specifying an HTTP method. (RuntimeError)
If you want to expose your action to both GET and POST, add `via: [:get, :post]` option.
If you want to expose your action to GET, use `get` in the router:
  Instead of: match "controller#action"

Comment: This is the output of grep filter: 
 root GET        /                                         redirect(301, /admin)                    admin_root GET        /admin(.:format)      admin/dashboard#index

But the redirection doesn't work...It's weird

Comment: Make sure you restart your server. Nothing that we've done has created an `admin_root` route, so be sure there's not other conflicting code. Instead of grepping, just run `rake routes` from your app directory and see what you get (after you restart). You should have a `root` route that calls `redirect(301, /admin)`, and an `admin` route that calls `admin/dashboard#index`

Comment: Try commenting out your `devise for :admin_users` line to see if that gets rid of the issue. You may have a naming conflict.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72700/discussion-between-collin-graves-and-halbano).

Comment: Can you help me a bit more Collin?